# How to get the type of constructor and dereference operator (decltype) without assuming any constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, decltype

Assume I have the following template:

```
template<typename T>
struct S
{
    typedef decltype(foo(T{})) TypeThatSomeFooFunctionReturns;
    typedef decltype(*TypeThatSomeFooFunctionReturns{}) TypeOfDereferenceOfWhateverFooReturns;
    ...
};
```

Now, this works just fine if the type T has a default constructor and if whatever "foo(T)" returns also has a default constructor.

But how would I write the template, if I don't want that assumption but also support any type T regardless of whether it (or any "foo(T)") provides constructors? (As I never construct these objects by myself anyway)

One clumsy solution that springs into my mind is to force the users of struct S to provide a template specialization for its arguments, basically unrolling the work of finding the correct type to whoever uses S:

```
template<typename T> struct S_Def { };
// User needs to provide these for each type
template<> struct S_Def<MyType> { typedef int* ReturnOfFoo; typedef int& DerefOfReturnOfFoo; };

template<typename T>
struct S
{
    typedef S_Def<T>::ReturnOfFoo TypeThatSomeFooFunctionReturns;
    typedef S_Def<T>::DerefOfReturnOfFoo TypeOfDereferenceOfWhateverFooReturns;
    ...
};
```

I'd like to avoid that burden.

Is there any other way to tell the compiler to just take whatever type any reachable function "foo(T)" returns for the typedef and then whatever any dereference operator on that type would return?

If not, are there reasons why? (Is it impossible? I'd be fine if ambiguity lead to a compile error.. Or too hard for the compiler to find?)

Thanks, Imi.

Comment: [`std::declval<T>{}`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might use [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval), and type_traits to modify the type:

```
template<typename T>
struct S
{
    using TypeThatSomeFooFunctionReturns = decltype(foo(std::declval<T>()));
    using TypeOfDereferenceOfWhateverFooReturns =
       std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(foo(std::declval<T>()))>;
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks, the std::declval seems to be what I was looking for, but I don't get the idea behind std::remove_reference_t (and neither seems my compiler).

But when I use this instead, it seems to work just fine :)

    `using TypeOfDereferenceOfWhateverFooReturns = decltype(*std::declval<TypeThatSomeFooFunctionReturns>());`

Comment: `std::remove_pointer_t<T*>` is `T`, `decltype(*std::declval<T*>())` is `T&`. There are several traits to modify types (to add/remove pointer/reference/const, ...). [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) is an important one.

Comment: Ah, I see. you edited to remove_pointer_t. Yes, that makes more sense :). In my specific case, I actually want T& (as this is indeed the "type that you get when dereferencing a pointer"), but good to know about the std::remove_X_t stuff for other occasions. :) thanks.